# Router-link inside component is not showing content

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, buefy

I'm having some issues with router-link, I have the followings:

Routes.js:

```
import Homepage from './components/homepage/Homepage'
import About from './components/About'

export default{
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Homepage
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        component: About
      }
    ]
 };
```

App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Routes from './routes';
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import Header from './components/header/Header'
import './plugins/element.js';
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';

Vue.use(Buefy, {});
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router: new VueRouter(Routes)
})

new Vue({
 render: h => h(Header),
}).$mount('#header')
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Header.vue

```
        <template>
        <b-navbar>
            <template slot="brand">
                <b-navbar-item tag="router-link" to="/">
                    <img
                        src="../../../assets/images/logo.png"
                        alt="elculatín, tu website de tiro con arco de referencia"
                    >
                </b-navbar-item>
            </template>
            <template slot="start">
                <router-link>
                    Inicio
                </router-link>
              ...
```

And my question is,

why router-link is not showing any content?

When I try to use this tag (as tag in b-navbar-item or directly as "< router-link >") inside header component, nothing appears.

If I put < router-link >whatever< /router-link > in welcome.blade.php it works.

I try different ways, with :name, :path and nothing worked.

I would really appreciate some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved, creating one "father" component App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <header-nav/>
        <div id="content">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import Header from "./header/Header"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    "header-nav": Header
  }
}

</script>
```

welcome.blade.php body:

```
    <body>
       <div id="app">           
       </div>
       <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

routes.js:

```
import Homepage from './components/homepage/Homepage';
import About from './components/About';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Homepage
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: About
        }
    ]
});
```

Apps.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import routes from './routes';
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import App from './components/App';
import './plugins/element.js';
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';

require('./bootstrap');

Vue.use(Buefy, {});

new Vue({
    router: routes,
    render: h => h(App),
  }).$mount('#app')
```

I guess the old structure is not compatible with vue-router.

Answer (score 0):

In your Routes.js file.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Homepage
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        component: About
      }
    ]
})
```

Then in your app.js file:

```
import router from './router'

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.title = to.meta.title || "Cat";
  next();
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(Header)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Header.vue

```
    <template slot="start">
      <b-navbar-item tag="router-link" :to="{ name: 'about' }">About</b-navbar-item>
    </template>
```

Comment: I already tried, but it doesn't work :(, is the same, nothing appears.